# SharePoint alert mail language

Tags: sharepoint, email, sharepoint-2010, alerts

Is it possible to change language of SharePoint (2010) alert emails?
Priority for out-of-box solutions.

Comment: Yes. In site collection I can select two different languages. Main is English and secondary is Lithuanian in which I want to get emails. Have tried to create alerts with Lithuanian language selected in GUI - didn't work.